# Iterate Object in Tabs in Vue

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuetify.js

I'm trying to iterate object instead of array in my `tabs`. How can i iterate it?

**Check my code below:**

```
<v-tabs v-model="tab" background-color="transparent" color="basil" grow>
   <v-tab v-for="order in orders" :key="order">{{ order }}</v-tab>
</v-tabs>
```

**JSON**

```
orders: {
  pending: {name: 'Bag'},
  approved: {name: 'Water'},
  cancelled: {name: 'Juice'}
}
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it as

```
<v-tabs v-model="tab" background-color="transparent" color="basil" grow>
   <v-tab v-for="(order,i) in orders" :key="i">{{ order }}</v-tab>
</v-tabs>
```

Comment: ```Don’t use non-primitive values like objects and arrays as v-for keys. Use string or numeric values instead```